Angular Routing from menu component to change maincomponent content display
I have a angular project setup as below:
app.component.html
  <app-top-header></app-top-header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <aside>
      <app-main-menu></app-main-menu>
    </aside>
    <main>
      <div class="wrapper_inner">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
       </div>
     </main>
   </div>

app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { MainMenuComponent } from './navigation/main-menu/main-menu.component';
import { TopHeaderComponent } from './top-header/top-header.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MainMenuComponent, TopHeaderComponent, RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
   // this.router.navigate(['splash-component']); // Navigate to the default route
  }

}

The app-main-menu is a separate component which has a list of li-a links and I would like the menu click to change the router-outlet content on the app.component page.
MainMenuComponent html (extract)
    
     <li><a href="#">Inventory</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
             <li><a routerLink="/inventory-component"
 routerLinkActive="active">Inventory</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

Setup routes in app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SplashComponent } from './views/splash/splash.component';
import { InventoryComponent } from './views/inventory/inventory.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    // Content Components
    { path: 'splash-component', component: SplashComponent },
    { path: 'inventory-component', component: InventoryComponent }
];

Currently nothing happens, but if I put the link on the app.component.html the route works. How can I go about using it from the menu?
Stackblitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cdynq2

Clicking the nested Inventory.
it does not.

UPDATE:
We need to remove the html and body tags from all the components, this is causing hydration errors in your code from SSR.
The routing did not work because, MainMenuComponent is standalone. Standalone components works independently on their own, without depending on the application as a whole. So we need to import RouterLink or RouterModule to trigger the navigation properly.
Stackblitz Demo

Firstly remove the body tags from app html. They should be only present in the index.html
<app-top-header></app-top-header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <aside>
      <app-main-menu></app-main-menu>
    </aside>
    <main>
      <div class="wrapper_inner">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
       </div>
     </main>
   </div>

Then ensure your index.html has the base href tag.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tour of Heroes</title>
  <base href="/"> <!-- should contain this -->

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>


Thanks, I have removed the body tags from the app html, and confirmed the index html has the correct content as above. The issue persists though.

@LF13 Please share a minimal code stackblitz with the issue happening and what needs to be fixed

Updated with a stackblitz link.

any ideas here?

@LF13 Im sorry I missed your stackblitz, I updated my answer, the routing seems to work fine now

Awesome, thank you so much.
